# Is [-a-z] the same as [a-zA-Z] in regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

From the `CI_Form_validation` class in Codeigniter, I see this function:

```
function alpha_dash($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

I think the `-` before `a-z` possibly means `[a-zA-Z]`, but entering `-a-z` in google does not give any useful result.

I would like to know if `[-a-z]` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

After seeing the `i`, I now know `[-a-z]` does not mean `[a-zA-Z]`. But what is it? There is already a `-` at the end.

Comment: You are right only one of them is needed.

Comment: So, this is my new favourite link: [Is there anything like RegexBuddy in the open source world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) - a few of those tools can not only design, but also explain regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-a-z` would be the hyphen character (-) and any letter between a and z. But then they've got it again later in the expression by itself which is redundant.

Answer (score 7):

No. It means "A hyphen or any of the letters between a and z".

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not. But your regex uses the `i` modifier on the end of the regex which signifies ignorecase.

so `/[a-z]/i` and `/[a-zA-Z]/` are the same thing

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z]` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z]`, **but** when you do a case insensitive search, of course it is the same. `[-a-z]` is simply a hyphen and the lowercase letters a-z, and the `/i` makes it lowercase + uppercase.

> The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search

from [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers given by @David and @Ryan, I would also like to add that if you are looking for something that means equal to `[a-zA-Z]` then it would be `/^[a-z]$/i` where `i` means case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know but I'm not a regex expert this is not the same.

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

means "Any upper and lowercase alphabetic character"

while

```
[-a-z]
```

means "Any minus or lowercase alphabetic character"

Answer (score 1):

`[-a-z]` will match hyphen (`-`) or any lowercase letter

`[a-zA-Z]` will match any lower or uppercase letter